# Showing diff's in the commit message

Tags: git

When one commits using `commit -a` a default editor pops up, prefilled with the contents of the `git status` command (but with all the lines preceeded by a pound sign).

Is it possible to have the output of `git diff` prefill the editor instead of the contents of `git status` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is made possible by the use of the `--verbose` flag; your full command becomes then `git commit -a --verbose` or, more concise, `git commit -av`.